# Sending content of videoview from one activity to next acvity's video view

Tags: java, android

I have a video playing in videoview in first activity. I want to to go to second activity and it should continue to play the same video (the video should not restart) in the videoview of second activity.
I am thinking to use intent to pass it's contents to video view of second activity , but I am wondering about how to resume the video from the same point.

Please help me. If any link or article is there related to that, please let me . It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend that you keep the video in a single activity. You are welcome to pass the current position of the video from activity to activity, but the user will experience a delay while the second activity loads the video to that point.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I have to change the videoview from full screen to some fixed sized videoview and to continue to play the video from same time without restarting it, how to go for it? How to deal with the time, so that it will start from its current position only?

Comment: Do that in one activity. Just change the size of the `VideoView`. Changing the size and position of widgets in Android is annoying (you need to modify the `LayoutParams` that controls the widget's size and position, then tell the framework that you modified the `LayoutParams`). However, it certainly works, and AFAIK it should work with `VideoView`.

Comment: I'd suggest to remove view from one layout, and add it into another layout instead of changing it's size, as @CommonsWare suggests. This way you will avoid all those *anoynig* things to handle other views' sizes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the best result, use "Fragment"  to display the video and also add another fragment to the same activity to display and do other stuff as you intend to do.